# FMS 16 cant get a green lock

Tags: filemaker

Good afternoon everyone,
Question about Uploading file in FMS 16 but getting an Orange Security Lock.

I already installed the Filemaker Server 16 and install SSL Certificate and domain from Go Daddy.

Then try uploading an existing file in Filemaker Pro Advanced 16, after choosing  local host and type the admin console credentials im getting the orange security lock and cant upload the file.  (Attached image)

I read in another thread to reinstall FMS and it should change it to a green lock, but even after a fresh reinstall, it hasn't changed it to green.
I can verify the certificate is good, Am I missing something?
I already purchase SSL certificate and Domain in Go Daddy, yet im getting in webdirect an error "Certificate is not valid".
Thanks in advance for any advice.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjtbH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you have entered IP address instead of domain name. That might be the reason for orange lock. SSL verifies the domain name, not IP address.

File Upload error says Encryption password is incorrect. You have enabled encryption on rest. Enter the correct encryption password. Once file uploaded, go to admin console, open the file. Enter the encryption password and save it. Hope, it fixes the issue.

[image]